# How to make disk quota full

Tags: unix, disk, diskspace, quota, mv

I am in a situation where i have to test mv(1) command while disk quota is exceeded.

Can anyone let me know the steps to create this.. i mean how can i make disk quota full on normal Unix test machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Download a bunch of porn. That'll recreate conditions most like those found in an enterprise environment.

Answer (score 3):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/usverg/test bs=1M count=1024
```

Where count is the number of MB you have to fill :)

Answer (score 1):

Either set a very small quota using whatever quota tools your OS and filesystems offer, or just fill up the filesystem by creating large files (using `dd` for example) until the quota is exceeded or very close to that.

Comment: Might be problematic if this is a production partition which you can't really mess with in this way.

Comment: You're not supposed to test things on production environments.

Comment: It might also be time consuming to fill up a (say) 150 GB partition. Artificially setting a low quota is a good idea though.

Comment: well, yes it can take a bit of time. The best is probably to do both (small but still realistic quota - i.e. not 64kb, filled with real files).

Answer (score 1):

I am also interested in doing "disk full" testing.  (I wrote some Java code that is sensitive to disk full scenarios, but I need to test it.)

To expand upon Noufal Ibrahim's idea #2, I did some research and found all the necessary commands to setup and teardown a mount for loop device.  This will allow you to create a tiny temporary mount.  You can fill it and do "disk full" testing.

My commands are for Debian Linux.  Your paths may vary slightly.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

_pwd=$(pwd -P)

usage() {
  echo "Setup or Teardown a loop device mount"
  echo
  echo "Normally, mount & umount require root-level access."
  echo "You may need to run this script via 'sudo'."
  echo
  echo "Usage 1: $0 setup FILE SIZE DEVICE MOUNT"
  echo "         FILE is the virtual file system in a single file"
  echo "         SIZE is the size of the virtual filesystem in 'dd' format"
  echo "              The minimum size appears to be 2M for ext3 file systems."
  echo "         DEVICE is the loop device"
  echo "         MOUNT is the mount point (directory)"
  echo
  echo "Usage 2: $0 teardown FILE DEVICE MOUNT"
  echo
  echo "Example: $0 setup ./data.ext3 2M /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop0"
  echo "Example: $0 teardown ./data.ext3 /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop0"
  echo
  exit 1
}

execute_command() {
  local command="$1"
  echo ">>> $command"
  eval "$command"
  local exit_code=$?
  if [ "0" != "$exit_code" ] ; then
    echo ">>> Command failed with exit code: $exit_code"
    exit 1
  fi
}

execute_bad_command() {
  local command="$1"
  echo ">>> $command"
  eval "$command"
  local exit_code=$?
  if [ "0" == "$exit_code" ] ; then
    echo ">>> Command unexpectedly successful!"
    exit 1
  fi
}

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
  usage
fi

if [ "setup" = "$1" ] ; then

  if [ "5" != "$#" ] ; then
    usage
  fi
  VFS=$2
  SIZE=$3
  DEVICE=$4
  MOUNT=$5

  # Create a file
  execute_command "dd if=/dev/zero of=${VFS} bs=${SIZE} count=1"

  # Format the file with ext3 filesystem
  # We need 'yes' here to ignore:
  #   ./data is not a block special device.
  #   Proceed anyway? (y,n)
  execute_command "yes | /sbin/mkfs -t ext3 -m 1 -v ${VFS}"

  if [ -d ${MOUNT} ] ; then
    execute_command "rmdir ${MOUNT}"
  fi

  # Create the mount point and enable read/write/execute for all users
  execute_command "mkdir -m 0777 ${MOUNT}"

  # Mount the file
  execute_command "mount ${VFS} ${MOUNT} -t ext3 -o loop=${DEVICE}"

  # Check the loopback setup
  # Example output: /dev/loop0: [0801]:17416195 (/home/kca/saveme/disk-full-test/data)
  execute_command "/sbin/losetup ${DEVICE}"

  # Test write
  execute_command "echo abc > ${MOUNT}/dummy.txt"

  # Clean-up test write
  execute_command "rm ${MOUNT}/dummy.txt"

  echo "Try to fill new mount with junk data:"

  # We expect to fail and see this error message:
  # dd: writing `/mnt/loop0/data': No space left on device
  execute_bad_command "dd if=/dev/zero of=${MOUNT}/junk bs=${SIZE} count=2"

  # Clean-up junk write
  execute_command "rm ${MOUNT}/junk"

  echo "Loop device mount setup and testing complete:"
  echo "${MOUNT}"

elif [ "teardown" = "$1" ] ; then

  if [ "4" != "$#" ] ; then
    usage
  fi
  VFS=$2
  DEVICE=$3
  MOUNT=$4

  # Unmount the file
  execute_command "umount ${MOUNT}"

  # Check loop device after mount.  We expect to fail.
  # loop: can't get info on device /dev/loop0: No such device or address
  execute_bad_command "/sbin/losetup ${DEVICE}"

  execute_command "rmdir ${MOUNT}"

  execute_command "rm ${VFS}"

  echo "Loop device mount teardown complete."

else
  usage
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can manually set your quota to something *really* low and then try your command.
2. You can create a (say) 10MB file and then format it as a ext3 partition and mount it using a loopback interface. Then, cd into that mountpoint and you'll have a maximum size of 10MB.